# Chebyshev Set and Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TAU.1972.1162342) by Parks and McClellan and have a question on *Chebyshev set*.

---

Consider a set of $n$ functions $\{f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_n(x)\}$ on [a,b]. They are called the *Chebyshev set* on $[a,b]$ when all the linear combinations
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(x)$$
have at most $n-1$ distinct roots on $[a,b]$ for any $a_1,\cdots,a_n$.

**Theorem:** Assume that $\{f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_n(x)\}$ is a Chebyshev set on [a,b]. Pick $n$ distinct points $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ from $[a,b]$ to define an $n\times n$ matrix $T$:
\begin{equation*}
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(x_1) & f_2(x_1)& \cdots & f_n(x_1) \\
f_1(x_2) & f_2(x_2)& \cdots & f_n(x_2) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_1(x_n) & f_2(x_n)& \cdots & f_n(x_n) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then $T$ is invertible.

---

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)^T$, and note that
$$
Ta = \pmatrix{
a_1f_1(x_1) + a_2f_2(x_1) + \cdots + a_n f_n(x_1)\\
a_1f_1(x_2) + a_2f_2(x_2) + \cdots + a_n f_n(x_2)\\
\vdots\\
a_1f_1(x_n) + a_2f_2(x_n) + \cdots + a_n f_n(x_n)}
$$
If the $f_i$ form a Chebyshev set, then there is no non-zero choice of $a$ such that the above vector is zero.  That is, $Ta = 0 \implies a = 0$.  This means that $T$ is invertible, since it has a trivial kernel (nullspace).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Can you please explain how the "at most $n−1$ distinct roots of the linear combination" kicks in the proof?

Comment: Note that "$Ta = 0$" means exactly that "the function $\sum a_i f_i(x)$ has roots $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$", which of course means that this function has $n$ distinct roots.  However, if the $a_i$ are not all equal to zero, this function can have at most $n-1$ distinct roots, which makes this outcome impossible.  Thus, we can only have $Ta = 0$ if every $a_i$ is zero. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Now I read *The Approximation of Functions: Linear theory* by John R. Rice to find out that the other direction of the theorem is also true: A function set forms a Chebyshev set if and only if the matrix T is invertible. (p. 55 of Rice's book.)

Comment: And yes. Your answer does help, Thanks.

Comment: @user19906 note that the other condition requires that we consider *every* possible set of distinct $x_i$.